# Dask hangs when using dask_xgboost train method

Tags: dask, xgboost, dask-ml

I am trying to reproduce the dask xgboost example from the dask-ml docs at http://ml.dask.org/examples/xgboost.html. Unfortunately, Dask doesn't seem to complete the training and I'm having a hard time tracking down the meaning of the errors and warnings. Here's my code:

```
def main():
    cluster = LocalCluster()
    dask_client = Client(cluster)

    x, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, chunks=10, n_informative=4, random_state=0)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.15)
    print("classification training...")
    params = {'objective': 'binary:logistic',
              'max_depth': 4,
              'eta': 0.01,
              'subsample': 0.5,
              'min_child_weight': 0.5}
    bst = dask_xgboost.train(dask_client, params, X_train, y_train, num_boost_round=10)

    dask_client.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the output:

```
classification training...
Socket Poll Error:WSAError-code=10022
Socket Poll Error:WSAError-code=10022
Socket Poll Error:WSAError-code=10022
Socket Poll Error:WSAError-code=10022
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 12376 exited with status 4294967295
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 3540 exited with status 4294967295
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 9424 exited with status 4294967295
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 12952 exited with status 4294967295
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of xgboost?